# Mysql accessing issues

Tags: unity

I've installed Mysql-5.6.19 in my Ubuntu 14.04 by downloading from mysql official website but after installing it I am not able to find where is the application & how can I start it & write queries into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a good place to start is the [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/get_started.html).  You may also want to look into installing mysql-workbench from the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: the tutorial link that you've sent me says page not found. After downloading the file it gets installed from ubuntu software centre    only but I don't know how do I start the application.

Comment: @vikash  I fixed the link - thanks for pointing out I had copied the web address incorrectly!

Comment: I found the installed directory but if I'm trying to execute the mysql executable file in bin directory it is not executing,pl tell me how do I execute the appliation

Comment: MySql should already be running in the background as a service - it does not have a neat graphic user interface.  You can check this with `ps -aux | grep -s mysql`

Answer (score 0):

Check the guide  on https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html. It has additional links on the topic. Basically, you need to :
1) setup the mysql and create a few databases.
2) Access the database through the mysql command-line.
3) Install mysql workbench for a gui for the common operations.